# i3 - setxkbmap clashes with bindsym in config

Tags: i3, xkb, notifications

I use a Manjaro i3 distribution on my laptop. Currently I switch layouts using Win+Space:

```bsh
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10 | grep options
options:    grp:win_space_toggle
```

I also want to use the default notification daemon (it's `dunst` that is called via `notify-send`) to show me what language I set after switching (the bar ins't always visible and I don't want it to be), so I go to my config file and write

```
bindsym $mod+space exec "notify-send 'Layout changed'"
```

and restart the i3. I wanted to check if this works and then write a script that displays the actual layout.
The problem is that there is no notification when I switch between layouts (but layouts do switch). I tested different bindings, e.g.

```
bindsym $mod+o exec "notify-send 'test'"
```

(works) and disabling setxkbmap toggling

```bsh
$ setxkbmap -option
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10 | grep options
$
```

(Win+Space now displays the notification, but when I add `grp:win_space_toggle` back it doesn't). What's the problem? Didn't find anything on the Web/StackExchange speciffically.

Comment: Confirm the problem. The `bindsym` is blocked when the same combination of keys appears in `setxkbmap`'s options.